# How to return json object by variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to return from JSON object "mail" for "name" which will be definie by variable C.

```
var c = "product3"

var text = '{"products":[' +
'{"name":"product1","mail":"jan@mail.com" },' +
'{"name":"product2","mail":"anna@mail.com" },' +
'{"name":"product3","mail":"john@mail.com" }]}';
```

In this case i want to return product3 john@mail.com

Comment: what have you already tried? where is your code?

Comment: why do you use a string and not an object literal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with ES6's [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) easily,

```
var textObj = JSON.parse(text)
var mail = textObj.products.find(itm => itm.name == c).mail
console.log(mail); // "john@mail.com"
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/17avcsub/)

Answer (score 1):

Using ES2015

```
let productsArr = JSON.parse(text).products;
let result=productsArr.find(product=>product.name===c);
console.log(result.mail);// output john@mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to return only values of your array which have a `name === "product3"`.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var c = "product3";

var requiredProduct = obj.products.filter(function(x) { 
  return x.name === c;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = '{"products":[' +
  '{"name":"product1","mail":"jan@mail.com" },' +
  '{"name":"product2","mail":"anna@mail.com" },' +
  '{"name":"product3","mail":"john@mail.com" }]}';

var data = JSON.parse(text);
var data1 = data.products;
console.log(data1[2].name)//get 3rd
console.log(data1[2].mail)//get 3rd
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  console.log(data1[i].name)//iterate here
  console.log(data1[i].mail)//iterate here
}
```

Do it like this

Answer (score 0):

first change `var text` to

```js
var text = {"products": [
{"name":"product1","mail":"jan@mail.com" },
{"name":"product2","mail":"anna@mail.com" },
{"name":"product3","mail":"john@mail.com" }
]};
```

then you can access the values as follows

```
var c = text.products[2].name  //returns product3 
var email = text.products[2].mail  //returns john@mail.com
```

Hope this helps.